# Castle Windsor Wcf Facility: How to inject WcfService-Instance into other components

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor

Given the following code:

```
public interface ISomeService() {...}

public class SomeService: ISomeService {...}

public class Consumer()
{
   public Consumer(ISomeService service) {...}
}
```

I would like to serve one instance of SomeService as Wcf service and inject *that same instance* into my Consumer classes. Here's my registration:

```
container.Register(
   Component.For<ISomeService>().ImplementedBy<SomeService>().AsWcfService(...).LifestyleSingleton(),
   Component.For<Consumer>()
);
```

Now when resolving a Consumer, I'll receive a different instance of SomeService than the one being served as WcfService, even though I specified the singleton lifestyle explicitely. 
Can this be done with the WcfFacility somehow? If not, could I just create that instance myself and publish it using the facility's internal features like automagic channel recreation in case of faults?

Comment: Are you creating the component that servers as WcfService manually ?

Comment: No, it is resolved by the container... I could of course instantiate it manually (as well as create a ServiceHost manually), but I would like to use the container since it's already there...

Comment: Is your service also a WCF singleton, has it the [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)] attribute declared on it ?